# How to make all buttons at equal distance from div

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

This is what I have presently -

```css
.box{
 background-color: #e61a39;
 width: 25%;
 float:left;
 margin: 0px;
 text-align: center;
 min-height: 380px;
}

#container{
 width: 90%;
 margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<section id="container">
 <div class="box">
  <img src="https://www.dominos.co.in/theme2/front/images/home/layer-7-1.png">
  <h1>Our Menu</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
   tempor incididunt ut labore et dolor</p>
  <button>Discover Pizza</button>
 </div>
 <div class="box">
  <img src="https://www.dominos.co.in/theme2/front/images/home/layer-7-3.png">
  <h1>Your Nearest Store</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolor</p>
  <button>Find Pizza Restaurants</button>
 </div>
 <div class="box">
  <img src="https://www.dominos.co.in/theme2/front/images/home/vector-smart-object.png">
  <h1>Birthday Party</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolor</p>
  <button>Book Now</button>
 </div>
 <div class="box">
  <img src="https://www.dominos.co.in/theme2/front/images/home/vector-smart-objectcopy-6.png">
  <h1>Catering</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolor</p>
  <button>Book Now</button>
 </div>
</section>
```

This code makes my buttons uneven. What can I do so that all the buttons are at the same distance from the bottom of the `box`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use position css properties.

```css
.box{
 background-color: #e61a39;
 width: 25%;
 float:left;
 margin: 0px;
 text-align: center;
 min-height: 380px;
    position:relative;
}
button{
        position:absolute;
        bottom: 10px;
        left:25%;
        right:25%;

}
#container{
 width: 90%;
 margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<section id="container">
 <div class="box">
  <img src="https://www.dominos.co.in/theme2/front/images/home/layer-7-1.png">
  <h1>Our Menu</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
   tempor incididunt ut labore et dolor</p>
  <button>Discover Pizza</button>
 </div>
 <div class="box">
  <img src="https://www.dominos.co.in/theme2/front/images/home/layer-7-3.png">
  <h1>Your Nearest Store</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolor</p>
  <button>Find Pizza Restaurants</button>
 </div>
 <div class="box">
  <img src="https://www.dominos.co.in/theme2/front/images/home/vector-smart-object.png">
  <h1>Birthday Party</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolor</p>
  <button>Book Now</button>
 </div>
 <div class="box">
  <img src="https://www.dominos.co.in/theme2/front/images/home/vector-smart-objectcopy-6.png">
  <h1>Catering</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolor</p>
  <button>Book Now</button>
 </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one way to do that

```css
.box{
 background-color: #e61a39;
 text-align: center;
 min-height: 380px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.box .content {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.box .button-wrapper {
  height: 40px;
}

#container{
 width: 90%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<section id="container">
 <div class="box">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="https://www.dominos.co.in/theme2/front/images/home/layer-7-1.png">
      <h1>Our Menu</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolor</p>
    </div>
    <div class="button-wrapper">
      <button>Discover Pizza</button>
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="box">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="https://www.dominos.co.in/theme2/front/images/home/layer-7-1.png">
      <h1>Our Menu</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolor</p>
    </div>
    <div class="button-wrapper">
      <button>Discover Pizza</button>
    </div>
 </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="https://www.dominos.co.in/theme2/front/images/home/layer-7-1.png">
      <h1>Our Menu</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolor</p>
    </div>
    <div class="button-wrapper">
      <button>Discover Pizza</button>
    </div>
 </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="https://www.dominos.co.in/theme2/front/images/home/layer-7-1.png">
      <h1>Our Menu</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolor</p>
    </div>
    <div class="button-wrapper">
      <button>Discover Pizza</button>
    </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

I used here flexbox (doesn't support ie10 and down).

This is a flexible way to do that because it's not absolute and doesn't depend on the height of the div above.
We define the height of button-wrapper and says to the 'content' div to have all of the rest of the 'box'.

Comment: put different content on each div :)

Comment: (+1)Hmm. Thanks. This works as well. However, I'm not really aware of what `flexbox` is, as I'm kind of new to html and css. So I'll accept the other answer, but thanks for your help! Hopefully I'll use this `flexbox` someday!